# Chrome Apps. jQuery.Templates analogs

Tags: templates, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, jquery-templates

I use jQuery.Template in my chrome app, but few days ago Chrome has updated Chrome Browser and Chrome Web Store and now i can't use `manifest_version:1` if I want publish my extension in Web Store. Installation apps from Desktop has been disabled too. So i MUST use `manifest_version:2`, but there are some troubles with `script-src 'unsafe-eval'` which were used in jQuery.Templates.

So `unsafe-eval` is disallowed for `script-src` directive.

Any suggestions of which JavaScript template engine can be used?

What i need from template engine:

- No any `new Function()` or `eval()` usage.
- Simple data access like in jQuery.Templates: `${my_variable}`
- Inline logic as: `{{if a==b}} ... {{else b == c}} ... {{/if}}`
- May be setting values to variables, but not necessarily: `${my_variable = 123, ''}`
- It must be like a plugin (not framework, i wont to rewrite my app).

**Note: No, i wont use sandboxed pages, i think it's very ugly solution.**

**Upd: thanks for answer. I've choosed Handlebars.js as a main template engine**

Comment: I just thought Id point out for you and anyone else seeing this that the restrictions on eval have been relaxed.... http://developer.chrome.com/trunk/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html#relaxing-eval ... hopefully this will mean more template engines will work again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Big thanks for your detailed answer but i found more elegant solution for me: Handlebars.js.

- **[Handlebars.js official site](http://handlebarsjs.com/)**
- **[Handlebars.js source code](https://github.com/downloads/wycats/handlebars.js/handlebars-1.0.0.beta.6.js)**

It has precompilation engine for templates and doesn't use `eval()` if using precompiled templates. It has very simple inline logic (I just can check that variable true or false) but it's very fast. =) You should try it for comparison. One moment: it uses NodeJS for precompilation. If you don't need it then just use `Handlebars.compile()`.

**Note: with `manifest_version: 2` you MUST use precompilation. If you try to use `Handlebars.compile()` you'll get error about CSP violation.**

If you have installed NodeJS you may try its precompilation engine using `npm install handlebars -g`. `-g` allows you to use `handlebars` in any project of your FS. You may need sudo this command. Next reload your terminal and cd to folder which consists of template files.

You need to migrate them to Handlebars.js syntax and add `.handlebars` extension for each file.
Then run `handlebars path/to/templates/*.handlebars -f js/templates.js`

If you load this js file after Handlebars.js you should found compiled templates here:

```
Handlebars.templates[your_template_file_name]
```

For example:

**my_template.handlebars**

```
<div>{{testing_template}}</div>
```

**main.js**

```
// example with RequreJS
require(["handlebars", "templates"], function(){
    var template = Handlebars.templates.my_template,
        rendered = template({
            "testing_template" : "some text right here"
        });

    console.log(rendered);
});
```

In console you'll see this:

```
> "<div>some text right here</div>"
```

Handlebars.js supports simple `{{#if}}` and `{{#unless}}` blocks as well as `{{#each}}` loops and custom helpers. Very powerful as i think.

Answer (score 0):

I just needed a template system and looked for something that will work with manifest version 2 and found this....
http://code.google.com/p/json-template/wiki/Reference
...no where in its code does it use eval.  Unfortunately I'm finding it a little hard figuring how to use it to its full extent and only just started looking at it myself, so my following comments may not be entirely true.
I don't use JQuery so cant really compare, but I think it will do what you want, mostly.
It doesn't do the inline code with script tags like jquery, but that pretty easy to do.  I wrote this pretty quickly to allow me to use inline templates.....

```
jsontemplate.inlineSCRIPT = function(source,templateoptions) {
    var templates = source.querySelectorAll('script[type="text/json-template"]');
    for (var i = 0; i < templates.length; i++) {

        var template = templates[i];

        var options = JSON.parse(template.getAttribute('options'));

        if (!options.object) continue;

        var sourceObjectBits = options.object.split('.');

        var sourceObject = window[sourceObjectBits[0]];

        for (var i = 1; i < sourceObjectBits.length; i++) {
            if (!sourceObject[sourceObjectBits[i]]) break;
            sourceObject = sourceObject[sourceObjectBits[i]];
        }

        if (i != sourceObjectBits.length) continue;

        var target;
        if (options.target) {
            options.target == 'self' ? target = template : target = document.querySelector(options.target);
        } else {
            target = template;
        }

        if (!target) continue;

        if (options.innerOuter) {
            options.innerOuter == 'inner' ? target.innerHTML = jsontemplate.expand(template.innerHTML, sourceObject,templateoptions) : target.outerHTML = jsontemplate.expand(template.innerHTML, sourceObject,templateoptions);
        } else {
            target.outerHTML = jsontemplate.expand(template.innerHTML, sourceObject,templateoptions);
        }
    }
}
```

....and then in my html I can have...

```
<script type='text/json-template' options='{"object":"a.b.details"}'>
    {# This is a comment and will be removed from the output.}
    {.section songs}
      {.repeated section @}
        {.if equals test title}
          test equaled title
        {.end}
      {.end}
    {.or}
    <p><em>(No page content matches)</em></p>
    {.end}
</script>
```

The templates got some conditionals but their pretty basic, like if variable = true then do this.  But I couldn't find anything for if variable equals variable do this.  You could add them using a custom predicate, but I haven't figured how to add one with arguments without altering the source for jsontemplate.... I'm sure you could, I just haven't figured how to yet.   If you do add a predicate you should be able to the conditions you want but the syntax in the template doesn't look great.  I added an if equals and the source for the template looks like this....

```
{.if equals test title}
  test equaled title
{.end}
```

...which means, if the variable test's value equals the value for title then do this block, you could then use the or block and more ifs for else's.  I cant tell you how to add one without modding the source for jsontemplate, but here's how to do it that way....
After the function `function _Pluralize(value, unused_context, args) {` line 76 add another function, like....

```
// Are two variables equal, gotta add the error checking
function _Mine(value, context, args) {
  var s, p;
  switch (args.length) {
    case 0:
      s = value;
      break;
    case 1:
       s = context.get(args[0]);
      break;
    case 2:
      s = context.get(args[0])==context.get(args[1]);
      break;
    default:
      // Should have been checked at compile time
      throw {
        name: 'EvaluationError', message: 'pluralize got too many args'
      };
  }
  return s;
}
```

..then in the compile function `function _Compile(template_str, options) {` look for the line `var default_predicates = PrefixRegistry([` (right under the function declaration) and add yours, like....

```
  // default predicates with arguments
  var default_predicates = PrefixRegistry([
    {name: 'equals', func: _Mine},
    {name: 'test', func: _TestAttribute}
      ]);
```

...Im sure you could use a predicate to set a variable as well, but haven't tried that.
Anyways, definitely worth having a look at.

Answer (score 0):

I did some research on this and for me the quickest way was to just to write some custom functions that replace the functionality of jQuery Template.

Comment: Thanks for answer but I already migrated from JQ Templates to Handlebars.js =)